# R datetime format issues

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am currently trying to determine the time and date on the observations in my dataset.
The date/timestamp is as follows:
1458024601.18659
1458024660.818
The observation are recorded ever minute.
I am trying to convert the above date/time stamp into something for understandable/ interpretable.
Could you please help me with this issue.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like seconds, but seconds starting from when? Typically, 1970-01-01:

```
> x = 1458024601.18659
> as.POSIXct(x, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2016-03-15 06:50:01 GMT"
```

So if you are expecting that timestamp to be that time, we've got the origin right.

If you are expecting a date in 1946, then `origin="1900-01-01"` is probably what you want.

Comment: Or is it a SAS date origin of 1960-01-01 or a Windows Excel origin of 1899-12-30 or Mac Excel with 1904-01-01 ? Oh.... the joys of date data.

Answer (score 1):

Since, according to your most recent post, the data is stored as a `factor` class, some further manipulations are required.

To convert the factor column into the required numeric class, this modification of @Spacedman's answer should work:

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(all_prices$timestamp)), origin="1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfect, except that i have another issue :(
I tried to run this code on the data.frame that i have. Unfortunately, i keep getting this following error after running the code.

> dates <- as.POSIXct(all_prices$timestamp, origin="2016-03-15")
>   Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Data "all_prices" is a data.frame.

> class(all_prices)
>   [1] "data.frame"

data "all_prices$timestamp" is a factor.

> class(all_prices$timestamp)
>   [1] "factor"